# gcc can't find phtread in cygwin

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, pthreads, samtools

I'm trying to install samtools () on cygwin.
I followed the various tricks [here](http://azaleasays.com/2014/09/29/install-samtools-in-cygwin/) and [here](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=16958) but looks like my problem is that i can't have a functioning `pthread`.
gcc is installed and works, `zlib` is installed and works and `ncurses` is installed and works + everything was added to the $PATH...but when i run `make` and it gets to the following line in Makefile:

```
gcc -pthread $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(AOBJS) libbam.a $(HTSLIB) $(LDLIBS) $(LIBCURSES) -lm -lz
```

then it throws an error because it doesn't recognize the unix command -pthread. now...pthread should be a part of the default installation in cygwin so I don't understand why this is not working...

any hint would be great!

Answer (score 0):

gcc's option `-pthread` is not available on Cygwin.